# Paypal Error : Merchant country unsupported

Tags: paypal

I am having an Paypal Merchant account in India and I am dealing with US and Canada using it.

I am trying to do direct payment from website, API is fully working with Sandbox account but in live mode it gives me this error :

```
L_ERRORCODE0:   10565 
L_SHORTMESSAGE0:    Merchant country unsupported. 
L_LONGMESSAGE0: The merchant country is not supported. 
L_SEVERITYCODE0:    Error
```

Is there any solution ?

Comment: The message is clear - Paypal is not supported in your country. Talk to Paypal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a limitation of Paypal's service, not programming.

Comment: I found the question useful. The question is 'is there any solution', which could be a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 10565 error (merchant country is not supported) means you're trying to submit a Payments Pro API call - Direct Payment in this instance -  from a country that does not support Payments Pro. Currently it is only available to US, UK, and Canadian merchants.

Here is a list of PayPal products and the countries that can use them:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/

Comment: The link you provide is dead

Comment: @sunny, now its supported all country ?

Comment: @Jatin No, you should check out the list of availability by Products in this answer to know if what you need is supported in a country.